# Removing the column headings off my Prettytable table

Tags: python, prettytable

My project is to code a program that mimics a simple percolation process.

When I run my program my output is a table with column headings as well.

How do I remove this? I only need my random numbers to appear.

```py
import random
from prettytable import PrettyTable


def get_dimensions():
    return input("Enter the dimensions Ex:(5x5): ")


def validate(dim):
    if dim == "":
        dim = "5x5"
    try:
        rows = int(dim[0])
        columns = int(dim[2])
        if not (3 <= rows <= 100) or not (3 <= columns <= 100):
            print("The inputs of the dimensions MUST BE in the range of 3-9 inclusive.\nTry again!")
            return [True, 0, 0]
    except:
        print("The input format is not valid!\nPlease read the instructions and try again!\n")
        return [True, 0, 0]
    return [False, rows, columns]


def create_grid(rows, columns):
    numbers = list(range(10, 100)) + ["  "]
    main = [[random.choice(numbers) for k in range(columns)] for i in range(rows)]
    column_names = list(range(columns))
    table = PrettyTable(column_names)
    for row in main:
        table.add_row(row)
    print(table)
    return main


def check_percolation(main, columns):
    for i in range(columns):
        for row in main:
            if row[i] == "  ":
                print("  NO", end=" ")
                break
        else:
            print("  OK", end=" ")


def main():
    while True:
        dimension = get_dimensions()
        validation = validate(dimension)
        not_validated = validation[0]
        rows = validation[1]
        columns = validation[2]
        if not_validated:
            continue

        main = create_grid(rows, columns)
        check_percolation(main, columns)

        cont = input("\n\nDo you wish to continue? (Y/N): ")
        if cont.upper() == "N":
            break


main()
```

#### expected output

[image: expected output]

#### output I got

[image: output i got]

Answer (score 1):

To hide column headings, put `table.header = False` before printing table in `create_grid`.

> **Style options:**
>
> [snip]
>
> - `header` - A boolean option (must be `True` or `False`). Controls whether the first row of the table is a header showing the names of all the fields.
>   – https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/

Alternatively, change the print to

```py
print(table.get_string(header=False))
```